# How can I append timestamp to rdd and push to elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, time, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new to spark streaming and elasticsearch, I am trying to read data from kafka topic using spark and storing data as rdd. In the rdd I want to append time stamp, as soon as new data comes and then push to elasticsearch.

```
lines.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        if(!rdd.isEmpty()){
        // rdd.collect().forEach(System.out::println);
        String timeStamp = new 
        SimpleDateFormat("yyyy::MM::dd::HH::mm::ss").format(new Date());
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(timeStamp.split("\\s+")));
        List<String> f = rdd.collect();


        Map<List<String>, ?> rddMaps = ImmutableMap.of(f, 1);
        Map<List<String>, ?> myListrdd = ImmutableMap.of(myList, 1);

        JavaRDD<Map<List<String>, ?>> javaRDD = sc.parallelize(ImmutableList.of(rddMaps));

        JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(javaRDD, "sample/docs");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Spark?

As far as I understand, spark streaming is for real time streaming data computation, like `map`, `reduce`, `join` and `window`. It seems no need to use such a powerful tool, in the case that what we need is just add a timestamp for event.

#### Logstash?

If this is the situation, Logstash may be more suitable for our case.
[image: kafka and ES]

Logstash will record the timestamp when event coming and it also has [persistent queue](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/persistent-queues.html) and [Dead Letter Queues](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/dead-letter-queues.html) that ensure the data resiliency. It has the native support for push data to ES (after all they are belong to a serial of products), which make it is very easy to push data to.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "logstash-%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

#### More

- for more about Logstash, [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/introduction.html) is introduction.
- [here](https://github.com/zzt93/log_egg/blob/master/bussiness.conf) is a sample logstash config file.

Hope this is helpful.

#### Ref

- [Deploying and Scaling Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/deploying-and-scaling.html)

Answer (score 0):

If all you're using Spark Streaming for is getting the data from Kafka to Elasticsearch a neater way–and not needing any coding–would be to use Kafka Connect.

There is an [Elasticsearch Kafka Connect sink](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-elasticsearch/docs/elasticsearch_connector.html). Depending on what you want to do with a Timestamp (e.g. for index routing, or to add as a field) you can use [Single Message Transforms](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_transforms) (there's an example of them [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/)).